implementation project fail in gradle with error "None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch"
After creating a new application Module ("design-kit") in my newly create Android project, I try to link my app to the new Module by adding the following to the dependency
implementation project(":design-kit")

However, that project implementation keep error out, while the other implementation works as shown in diagram below (red colour shown in Android Studio).

I tried sync, and it errors out as below
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.implementation: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Is there anything I need to do, to make implementation project valid in my project I need to do?
I tried ask ChatGPT, and to no avail.

It turns out, I'm on build.gradle.kts file instead of build.gradle file.
The syntax should be
    implementation(project(":design-kit"))

